# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build Query Widget

Tags: flutter

I have a problem with Graphql Flutter.
I am trying to display a search list retrieved with graphql.

But flutter tells me:

> This widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.

I added some Future Builder to avoid this kind of issue but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work

this is my code:

```
Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Flexible(
                                    flex: 5,
                                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                                      height: 42.0,
                                      width: width,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                        color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                                        boxShadow: [
                                          BoxShadow(
                                            color: const Color(0x29000000),
                                            offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                            blurRadius: 12,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      child: Form(
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                          children: [
                                            Flexible(
                                              flex: 1,
                                              child: Container(
                                                width: 17.0,
                                                height: 17.0,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                    image: const AssetImage(
                                                        'assets/images/XDSearch.png'),
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            Flexible(
                                              flex: 6,
                                              child: TextFormField(
                                                onChanged: (value){
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    textSearch = value;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                    focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                    errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                    disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                                    hintText: 'Recherche'
                                                ),
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
                                                  fontSize: 16,
                                                  color: const Color(0x8c000000),
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                ),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                                focusNode: _focus,
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  clickOnBar == false ? Flexible(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                      children: [
                                        Container(
                                          width: 30.0,
                                          height: 30.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: const AssetImage('assets/images/XDProfil.png'),
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ) : Container()
                                ],
                              ),
                              textSearch != null && textSearch != 'undefined' && textSearch.isNotEmpty  ? FutureBuilder(
                                  builder: (context, projectSnap) {
                                    return Query(
                                      options: QueryOptions(
                                          documentNode: gql("""
                                            query getListSearch(\$text : String!){
                                              listSearchProPages(text: \$text) {
                                                categorie {
                                                  idCat
                                                  title
                                                }
                                                subCat {
                                                  idSubCat
                                                  title
                                                }
                                                pagePro {
                                                  idPagesPro
                                                  title
                                                }
                                              }
                                            }
                                          """
                                          ),
                                          variables: <String, dynamic>{
                                            "text": textSearch,
                                          },
                                          pollInterval: 10
                                      ),
                                      builder: (QueryResult result, {VoidCallback refetch, FetchMore fetchMore}){
                                        print(result);

                                        if (result.hasException) {
                                          return Text(result.exception.toString());
                                        }
                                        if (result.loading) {
                                          return Text('Loading');
                                        }

                                        var tmpObject = {
                                          "categorie": result.data['listSearchProPages'].first['categorie'],
                                          "subCat":  result.data['listSearchProPages'].first['subCat'],
                                          "pagePro":  result.data['listSearchProPages'].first['pagePro'],
                                        };

                                        return FutureBuilder(
                                            future: updateListSearch(tmpObject),
                                            builder: (context, projectSnap){
                                              if(tmpObject.length > 0) {
                                                ListView.builder(
                                                    itemCount: tmpObject.length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                      print(tmpObject);
                                                      final repository = tmpObject[index];
                                                      print(repository["categorie"]
                                                          .first['title']);
                                                      return Text(
                                                          repository["categorie"]
                                                              .first['title']);
                                                    }
                                                );
                                              }else {
                                                return Container();
                                              }
                                              return Container();
                                            }
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );
                                  }
                              ) : Container()
                            ],
                          ),
```

Do you have the solution ?

Comment: This is related to your updateListSearch() method. Please share it too.

Comment: thanks you @Akif my updateListSearch is a setState tmpObject -> listSearch. 
But I need to do a setstate but I don't know where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not create a new future on every call of the build method as you do now.

You need to create a future *once* (or maybe more often, but certainly not on every build) and then use *that* future in your build method:

Create a variable of your future type in your state class.

In your initState method, create the future, by assigning the result of `updateListSearch(tmpObject)` to your variable.

In your build method, use the *variable* as your parameter for the future in the FutureBuilder.